# angular firebase configuration Already using account

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angularfire2

Trying to configure firebase in my angular app.
Created a new firebase project in the console and want to create a new angular project using firestore in the new firebase project.

However, get error "Already using account aa@xxx.xx for this project directory." see log below.
The local project directory is newly created and contains only this test project.
Why do I get this error and how can I work around it?

C:\firebase\test-firebase>ng add @angular/fire
Node.js version v21.1.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1075 bytes)
√ Packages installed successfully.
? What features would you like to setup? ng deploy -- hosting, Firestore
Using firebase-tools version 13.0.0
? Which Firebase account would you like to use? (Use arrow keys)
[Login in with another account]

> aa@xxx.xx (node:28068) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userla? Which Firebase account would you like to use? aa@xxx.xx
> **Already using account aa@xxx.xx for this project directory.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I have angular 16
Firebase-tools version 13 gives me that error
firebase -V
you can see the version
I installed 12.9.1 and it worked.
npm i -g firebase-tools@12.9.1
But you have to install and then generate the angular project again

Comment: Please provide a link to supporting documentation or provide an example of how the behavior changes after changing versions

Comment: I'm sorry I can't satisfy your requirement but my English is just enough to read and I just tried to help my colleague as best I could.
If you think the comment is not helpful, I will delete it.

Comment: Don't remove this comment! This saved my life today :)
I tried everything but this was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way that I can resolve this was using Firebase commands.

Try to use first `firebase serve` to check if your project is served correctly on the browser and then use `firebase deploy` to deploy your application on Firebase.