# Issues with ng add @angular/fire Error: Already using account xxx@gmail.com for this project directory

Tags: angular, firebase

I am very new to Firebase and this is only my second project

Currently, I am following the Google tutorial ( Building a web application with Angular and Firebase  |  Google for Developers ), and I am in the 9th step.

the problem is every time I try using ( ng add angular/fire ), I stop at Which Firebase account would you like to use? Since I already have an account I choose it but I get an
Error: Already using account xxx@gmail.com for this project directory.
and the installation stops,

I tried looking online for a solution but nobody seems to have this issue, or at least none that I can find,

can somebody explain what the problem is? and how to fix it ?

I tried moving the project to another directory
I tried creating a new angular project but I still have the same problem
I tried removing Firebase and adding it again

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what you're doing without requiring the reader to know that there is a tutorial and follow it along with you.  Your question should contain everything we need to know to understand the problem.

Comment: Here is the comment which helped me to get going
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742990/3825134